# Basic Javascript i cannot understand

Tags: javascript

```
var MyCountry = "trolling";
console.log(MyCountry).length;
console.log(MyCountry).substring(0, 3)
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'console.log(MyCountry).length')

Comment: From Trolling? Classy.

Answer (score 2):

You're putting `.length` and `.substring` on the result of `console.log()`, which is always `undefined`. Put them inside on the `MyCountry` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want. You're closing your console.log() too soon both times.

```
 var MyCountry = "trolling";
 console.log(MyCountry.length);
 console.log(MyCountry.substring(0, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` returns undefined, so you're calling `.length` on undefined.

If you want to log the length of MyCountry do `console.log(MyCountry.length)`

Also, `console.log(MyCountry.substring(0, 3))`